# How to insert new line in the SharePoint error message?

Tags: 2013, error, event-receivers

I have written a code in event receiver which validates the user entered. My code is complete but the message I want to pass comes in the sinle line.
I want to display the message in multiple lines.

My code is:

```
if (coll.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (SPListItem item in coll)
    {
        SPFieldUserValueCollection userColl = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)item[FieldNames.Man];

        var taxonomyField = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(FieldNames.Dept) as TaxonomyField;
        var fieldValue = item[taxonomyField.Id] as TaxonomyFieldValue;

        string dept = fieldValue.Label;

        foreach (SPFieldUserValue val in userColl)
        {
            itemPos = Users.FindIndex(v => v.ID == val.User.ID);
            if(itemPos > -1)
                ErrorMsg += val.User.Name + " has Department: " + dept + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}

properties.ErrorMessage = "Please Check Users: " + ErrorMsg;
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
```

The error message appears like:
[image]

I want to display message like:

Please Check Users: Riyaz Kalva has Department: Department 1 
                    Kalpesh Vaghela has Department: Department 1

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

simple options are:

• string.Format:

```
string x = string.Format("first line{0}second line", Environment.NewLine);
```

•String concatenation:

```
string x = "first line" + Environment.NewLine + "second line";
```

You could also use \n everywhere, and replace:

```
string x = "first line\nsecond line\nthird line".Replace("\n",
                                                         Environment.NewLine);
```

Note that you can't make this a string constant, because the value of Environment.NewLine will only be available at execution time.

In case of string builder, you can use the follwoing,

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(first);
sb.AppendLine(); // which is equal to Append(Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append(second);
return sb.ToString();
```

In place of assigning the string to the event receiver, you can do it in the follwoing way,

```
properties.ErrorMessage = "Please Check Users: " + System.Environment.NewLine + ErrorMsg;
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085739/how-to-insert-newline-in-string-literal)

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.NewLine` is just going to insert the appropriate white space for a newline, but browsers generally ignore extraneous white space.  If you want the browser to interpret it as a newline, you need to insert the HTML tag for a newline, or `<br/>`.